# Anchor tags in HTML with scroll transitions do not correctly link to each other

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this fixed menu bar:

I have all of these sections on one long webpage, with each link connecting to somewhere else on the page. I also have the following JavaScript, which is used to make the links scroll to their locations instead of jumping to them:

However, when a user clicks a link, in the menu bar, it only scrolls to the top (For example, if I am halfway down the page and click "our services" it jumps to "home" instead). I believe it has something to do with the first line of my js, but I am not a js expert. Any ideas?

```js
    //Make anchor tags scroll to link instead of jumping
    $('a[href^=\\#]').on("click",function(e){
        var sc= $(this.hash);
        var sc=sc.length&&t||$('[name='+this.hash.slice(1)+']');
        if(sc.length){
            var tOffset=sc.offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:tOffset-20},'slow'); //Speed of transition
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu header hidden-sm-down">
   <a href="#home" title="Home">Home</a>
   <a href="#about" title="About">About</a>
   <a href="#services" title="Experience">Our Services</a>
   <a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

UPDATE: I should add, since it seems to be part of the issue, that I have some additional js that adds classes to sections as you scroll down. This is used to make the menu bar css change as you scroll. The code for this is:

```
//Make the top menu bar appear when the user scrolls down on the page
$(window).scroll(function() {    
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            var objectSelect = $("#changeHeader"); // Where the change should occur
            var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
            if (scroll > objectPosition) {
                $(".header").addClass("headerAppear"); // Adds class "headerAppear" once scrolling past the objectPosition
            } else {
                $(".header").removeClass("headerAppear", {duration:500});
            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? `sc.length&&t`

Comment: The nav bar scrolls to various points on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what are you trying to do, but your task is much easier than your implementation. Get the element from the `href` attribute

```js
$('a[href^=\\#]').on("click",function(e){
    var sc= $($(this).attr('href'));
    if(sc.length){
        var tOffset = sc.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop:tOffset-20
        },'slow'); 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```css
.block {
  height: 1000px;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu header hidden-sm-down">
    <a href="#home" title="Home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about" title="About">About</a>
    <a href="#services" title="Experience">Our Services</a>
    <a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class='block' id='home'>Home</div>
  <div class='block' id='about'>About</div>
  <div class='block' id='services'>Our Services</div>
  <div class='block' id='contact'>Contact</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: plus 1 For this working to scroll not jump, but I updated my question with more code on my page.

Comment: @AdamH I don't see a question in the update. Please specify the problem for the update. And also HTML for changeHeader would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This seems that you are using Bootstrap. The simple is to use `query.easing` and `scrolling-nav` libraries. This will reduce all you javascript code and add smooth scroll to the section.

I have created fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/tr5dm3tx/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I figured out my mistake. Turns out I was running a Jquery that was higher than supported for my code. Switched to 2.1.1 and I don't have any more issues. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't put what should be comments as answer. Accept given answers or write your own and accept it if you figured out yourself. Refer to it as a person googles some problem and will find your question. The answer must contain only the answer. Short and clear as possible. If you wan't to thank someone do it in comments